# Replace from URL everything after forward slash

Tags: javascript, url

I want to use JavaScript to remove from href everything that starts with the forward slash.

This snippet removes from href everything that starts with the hash:

```
var url = this.href.replace(/#.*/,'');
```

How can I modify it to remove everything that starts with the forward slash?

Comment: Replace `#` with a forward slash. Since it is also the delimiter for regex literals, you have to escape it.

Comment: Are you wanting to convert `http://example.com/foo` to `http://example.com` or just `http:`?

Comment: What did you try? What problem did you have? Do you understand that regex?

Comment: I want http://example.com @James

Comment: In that case, you should probably just use `this.hostname`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you want something like `/(\/\/[^\/]+)?\/.*/`, and then to keep the first capture, if any..

```
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884753/replace-from-url-etc'
    .replace(/(\/\/[^\/]+)?\/.*/, '$1');
// "http://stackoverflow.com"
'stackoverflow.com/questions/16884753/replace-from-url-etc'
    .replace(/(\/\/[^\/]+)?\/.*/, '$1');
// "stackoverflow.com"
```

`(pattern)?` means an optional capture group
`\/\/` means match `//`
`[^\/]+` means match one or more consecutive non-`/`
`\/` means now match a `/`
`.*` matches almost everything else
`$1` means capture group 1, if this was empty, will give an empty string.

In this RegExp, capture group one would be

```
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"
      ^-------$1--------^
```

Comment: This seems more complicated than just removing everything after the first slash. Are there any advantages to this approach?

Comment: @WaleedKhan it works irrespective of whether you start `http://example.com/blah` or `example.com/blah`